# In a member function, can this == NULL?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have the following class

```
struct FooList {
    int data;
    FooList *next;

    // basic constructor
    FooList(int d, FooList *n): data(d), next(n) {}
    // basic destructor
    ~FooList() { if (next) delete next; }

    FooList *functional_append(FooList *) const;
};
```

And then in my implementation, I define

```
FooList *FooList::functional_append(FooList *other) const {
    if (this == NULL)
        return other;
    else
        return new FooList(data, next->functional_append(other));
}
```

Does the condition on the second line make any sense?  Will `this` ever be `NULL`?  I know that if `functional_append` was declared `virtual` then this would throw a segmentation fault once `this == NULL`, but as a simple member function would it still work like I expect it to?

---

Note: I am looking for a reason why the above will or will not work (like the equivalent C code), not just "No, it can't happen" or "Yes, if force it to like this ...".

Comment: In short: No it can't be `NULL`.

Comment: If this is NULL you have a serious problem.

Comment: Yes, it can. Initialize `FooList *ptr = NULL;`, and then call `ptr->functional_append(...);`.

Comment: It is UB that very often works.  Until some hapless victim uses it as a MI base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Will this ever be NULL?*

Yes, this could be NULL. But that would be the case your program is behaving incorrectly ( i.e maybe corrupted memory or something else). Then there would be many more things to check for rather than putting `this == NULL`.

In normal scenarios `this` can never be NULL as when you call a function on a valid object then `this` is implicitly passed by compiler to that function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
 MyClass* p = NULL;
 p->foo();
```

and `foo()` might by actually called, and a test for `this == NULL` yields `true`.

Nevertheless the above sample is simply raising undefined behavior, at the point when `p` is dereferenced. A check for `this == NULL` to determine any further logical behavior, is beyond all hope.

Comment: Well I believe you never be able to see this as NULL in this scenario...

Comment: @ravi I didn't say that (besides in my comment). I just stated it's going to be UB.